# Disable save as prompt when downloading a file using VB.NET

Tags: html, vb.net, save, prompt

I found some topics about disabling the download prompt but I never really found what I needed.

I have a windows Form with a webbrowser in it. I can browse the webbrowser programmitcally to a site where I want to download a file.
The file isn't an actual URL, but it's more like a link to another page. When I click the link using :

```
item.InvokeMember("click")
```

(the "item" is an HtmlElement representing the link I want to click)

So far so good, but the file isn't downloading to my default Downloads folder when clicked. Instead, I get a prompt to Save or Open the downloaded file.

How can I disable this savefile dialog prompt, and download the file to my default download folder?

And instead of downloading it to my default download folder, can I save the downloaded file into a path of my choice?

Thanks in advance!

PS. 
This doesn't work because It's not a URL to a file, but a link to a downloadpage

```
my.computer.network.downloadfile("URL", "DESTINATION")
```

Greetz
Kristof

Comment: If you don't know the path to the file you can't download it without the dialog

Comment: Can I fill in the dialog progammatically then?

Comment: No ... and all this for a good reason, security, so the owners of sites can at least have some control of how/who download their files